# Adding custom Floating menu option in SharePoint Document Library Item Level to copy row and create new row with copy

Tags: sharepoint, menu

Add Floating Menu Item to the Page Library "E.g. Copy Item".

Once user selects option, It should

1. Copy entire selected row's information including Page.
2. Let user rename the page.
3. Create a new row in the same Page Library.
4. Save the copied information in the newly created row.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing out the entire answer, here's some guidance on a way of doing this:

1) Create a **CustomAction** in the **EditControlBlock** for the **Page Content Type** (or related) containing a **UrlAction** that goes to a custom **ASPX** Page, passing required parameters through the aforementioned **UrlAction** (look into **{ListId}** and **{ItemId}** tokens). In this ASPX page, have a field to enter the new Page Name, and then a button to complete the copy and return to the list.

Here is a good starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460194%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Everything else in bold you should research.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. This is a good starting point to think about it.